# Duplicated tr in table, impossible to clear a table element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, if someone can help.
I am connected to a database. 
I have this table and I want -when I push the send button- to send the info to my database. This works fine.
TWhen I press the 'list data' button I want to append a tbody element to the table.I wrote this fllowing code:

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="age"/>

<table id='client'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="send"/>
<input type="button" id="showList" value="list data"/>

... 
.... $.get().then(displayClients);
...
function displayClients(response) {
        let table = $('#clients');
        let tbody = $('<tbody>');

        tbody.remove();

        for (let data in response) {
            let name = response[data]['name'];
            let age = response[data]['age'];

            let tr = $('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>').text(name))
                .append($('<td>').text(age))

            tbody.append(tr);
        }
        table.append(tbody);
    }
```

The problem is that even though I remove the entire tbody in the beginning of the function it doubles the records every time. I push send instead of adding only the last one.

Comment: A shot into the dark: You don't create a new tbody, you add the old object to your table.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting elements by tagname in jQuery, you simply use the name of the tag without `<>`, so instead of `jQuery('<tbody>');` it should be `jQuery('tbody');`

Also, you probably don't want to use `remove` as this actually **removes** the element from the DOM. Maybe that causes some trouble in combination with the wrong jQuery-selector. An alternative would be `.empty()`, which simply removes all the content of the element, instead of the element itself. Then you can also omit the line `table.append(tbody)`.

*Here is my guess what's happening:*

You don't actually select the tbody but something else (experimenting with `jQuery('<tagname>')` yielded some weird results for me. Nevertheless, `remove` returns a `jQuery`-Object that contains a collection of DOM-elements (http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) - Which element that is/was, isn't really of concern, since you `remove`d it.

Then you start adding new stuff to an empty collection in the `jQuery` object with `tbody.append(...)`. Finally you append all that new stuff to the `table` element, which then simply adds the new elements to the `tbody`, since the initial `tbody` was never touched because of the wrong selector.

Comment: Thank you! I really fixed it using .clear() instead of .remove().